# WiFi adhoc network creation in Raspberry Pi

Tags: raspberry-pi, wifi, adhoc

I am trying to create a WiFi Ad-hoc network/ Hotspot in my Raspberry Pi but no success.

I tried from the following links

- novitiate.co.uk/?p=183
- lcdev.dk/2012/11/18/raspberry-pi-tutorial-connect-to-wifi-or-create-an-encrypted-dhcp-enabled-ad-hoc-network-as-fallback/
- sirlagz.net/2013/02/10/how-to-use-the-raspberry-pi-as-a-wireless-access-pointrouter-part-3b/

The error is as follows:

> Starting advanced IEEE 802.11 management: hostapdSegmentation fault

When I googled for the above error, some forums suggested to hardcode the path of the WiFi adapter driver. When I hard-code it, I am encountering the new error

> Starting advanced IEEE 802.11 management: hostapdrmdir[ctrl_interface]:  Operation not permitted
> Segmentation fault

I am not able to start the hostapd service.

Answer (score 0):

The above links you followed are supposed to work. I followed [this](http://elinux.org/RPI-Wireless-Hotspot) link and my Wifi Hotspot was up in few minutes.
I think your Wifi Adapter might not be supporting straight way

Suggestions to troubleshoot :-

1>Check  **/var/log/messages**  and **/var/log/syslog**

2>check the list of wifi adapters supported for RPi [here](http://elinux.org/RPi_USB_Wi-Fi_Adapters)

and make sure your configuration is correct as per the above tutorial.

Answer (score -1):

I have a RTL8188CUS device, and installing the Jenssengers hostapd worked for me
https://jenssegers.com/43/Realtek-RTL8188-based-access-point-on-Raspberry-Pi

**All credits to Jenssegers.**

Remove old hostapd

```
sudo apt-get autoremove hostapd
```

Download the Jenssegers solution

```
wget https://github.com/jenssegers/RTL8188-hostapd/archive/v2.0.tar.gz
tar -zxvf v2.0.tar.gz
cd RTL8188-hostapd-2.0/hostapd
```

Make and install

```
sudo make
sudo make install
sudo service hostapd restart
```